# Ubuntu upgrade hangs on 'apt-get -f install'

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have done something to my Ubuntu box and I'm not sure what... TBH I'm not even sure how I got here I've been looking at it for so long...

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-127-generic
```

I have the following image header

```
flare@Flare:~$ sudo dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic       4.4.0-112.135                             
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic 4.4.0-112.135                             
flare@Flare:~$ sudo dpkg --list | grep linux-headers
ri  linux-headers-4.4.0-112             4.4.0-112.135                             
rH  linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic     4.4.0-112.135
```

When I try to run

```
$ sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

everything looks OK and then it finishes with...

```
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.127.133) but it is not installed
                 Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 4.4.0.127.133) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When I run

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

it hangs on

```
Fetched 58.6 MB in 9s (6,401 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 62742 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135) ...
```

Is there anything I can do?  Thanks!

```
flare@Flare:~$ sudo df -h
[sudo] password for flare:
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       396M  5.6M  390M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/Flare--vg-root   90G  2.5G   83G   3% /
tmpfs                       2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                       2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                   236M   56M  168M  25% /boot
cgmfs                       100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                       396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: "Plenty of free space", what is that? Please post the output from `df -h`

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic`. If you had a /boot space problem for too long, you missed a couple upgrades. Reinstalling those two metapackages will catch your kernels up to date.

Comment: Thanks!  Still asking me to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct